# How to test openFileInNewWindow behaviour and pass the sonarqube

Tags: testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit, redux-mock-store

I'm currently testing a stepper component integrated with redux toolkit. Whithin this component, there's a method called postLogOfDocument, please review the provided code:

My Stepper component:

```
            const StepperDownloader = ({ propietario, useremail, ordenCliente }) => {
       const {
    data: { activeStep, activeStepFailed, messagesStepper, showTextAreaMotivo },
  } = useAppSelector(selectStepperDownloader);
  const { motivos } = useMotivosDocumentosLogs();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

      const [motivo, setMotivo] = useState("");
    
      const isStepFailed = (step) => {
        return step === activeStep;
      };
    
      const postLogOfDocument = useCallback(
        );
    
      const handleGetDocument = useCallback(
        async () => {
          try {
            getRemitoByPropietarioAndOrdenCliente
            ("Getting document...");
            getRemitoAdicional("Getting additional document...");
           
            await postLogOfDocument(3, true, true);
          } catch (error) {
                     }
        },
        []
      );
    
      useEffect(() => {
        handleGetDocument();
      }, [handleGetDocument]);
    
      const handleButton = async () => {
        if (motivo.length > 0) {
         ("Button clicked, handling action...");
          // dispatching nextStep and setShowTextAreaMotivo
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <Box data-testid="stepper-container">
          <Stepper activeStep={activeStep}>
            <Step key="StepLabel">
              <StepLabel>Step Label</StepLabel>
            </Step>
          </Stepper>
          <Box>
            {!showTextAreaMotivo && activeStep !== 1 && (
              <Typography>Message Step: {messagesStepper.messageStep}</Typography>
            )}
            {showTextAreaMotivo && (
              <Box data-testid="select-container">
                <Select
                  value={motivo}
                  onChange={(e) => setMotivo(e.target.value)}
                >
                  <MenuItem value="Motivo1">Motivo 1</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Motivo2">Motivo 2</MenuItem>
                </Select>
                <Button onClick={handleButton}>Descargar</Button>
              </Box>
            )}
          </Box>
        </Box>
      );
    };
    
    export default StepperDownloader;
```

Need to be pass in Sonar:

```
  const postLogOfDocument = useCallback(
async (maxRetries: number, pdfInBlob?: Blob | null, pdfAdicionalBlob?: Blob | null) => {
  try {
    await postDocumentosLogs({
      motivo,
      ordenCliente,
      propietario,
      username: useremail,
    });

    if (pdfInBlob) {
      openFileInNewWindows(pdfInBlob);
    }
    if (pdfAdicionalBlob) {
      openFileInNewWindows(pdfAdicionalBlob);
    }
    if (pdfInBlob || pdfAdicionalBlob) {
      dispatch(setMessageStep("text"));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (maxRetries > 0) {
      await postLogOfDocument(maxRetries - 1, pdfInBlob);
    }
    if (pdfInBlob) {
      dispatch(setMessageStep("some text"));
    }
  }
},
[motivo, ordenCliente, propietario, useremail, dispatch]
```

);

I need guidance on how to effectively test the behavior of this function. Specifically, I want to ensure that if a blob is successfully received, it opens in a new window. How can I test this functionality in a React and ensure that the code compiles with Sonarqube's standards?

below is my test:

```
 test("should display success message and open PDFs in new windows when receiving blob successfully", async () => {
jest.clearAllMocks();
const openSpy = jest.spyOn(window, "open").mockImplementation();

(useAppSelector as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue({
  data: {
    activeStep: 2,
    activeStepFailed: null,
    messagesStepper: { messageStep: "success message." },
    showTextAreaMotivo: false,
  },
}); renderWithProviders(<StepperDownloader {...props} />);
expect(screen.getByText("success message.")).toBeInTheDocument();// test passed
```

In the test part, I enable mock the success message, but it's not enough.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you wanting to unit test the `StepperDownloader` component, as a whole, or do you want to specifically test the function passed to the `useCallback` hook? Is the unit test for the entire function, or specifically that `openFileInNewWindows` was called with an expected payload? Please [edit] to clarify the issue/problem and what you need specific help with, and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

Comment: Hi Drew, thank you for your reply. I recently added the entire component for your reference. I hope the provided component code is clear. Thank you in advance.